# Redux store data being reset upon "getServerSideProps" being called; not persisting

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper

**Overview:** I have a `TypeScript` `NextJS` project that I am using `Redux-toolkit` with to manage state. My file structure for my `Redux` store and pages are as follows:

[image]

(`/store` is at the root of my project)

[image]

**Project layout:** I have 2 pages (`index.tsx` and `other.txs`), both these pages display a `counter` variable which I get from my store (`const counter = useSelector(selectCounter)`, then displaying `{counter.count}` on the pages). I also have an "increase count by 1" button on each page. Pressing them on either page updates my `Redux` store through `state.count++` via one of my reducers.

**The Problem:** My `index.tsx` page also has a `getServerSideProps` function which dispatches an action to increment the `counter` by 1 (same action as the buttons). This works well upon first loading the website to `index.tsx`, my counter on-screen defaults to 1 because of the `getServerSideProps` (`initialState: {count: 0}`, so incrementing 0 by 1 with `getServerSideProps` renders it instantly as 1). I also use the `next/link` (`<Link/>`) component to navigate between the 2 screens (`index.tsx` & `other.tsx`).

I can increment the counter value by n amount on the `index.tsx` page, `<Link/>` to the `other.tsx` page, and have the count value persist, however, when I navigate BACK to the `index.tsx` page, my `getServerSideProps` method doesn't work (it only has increment count by 1 in it), instead, my count gets reset back to 1 (like new again). **Why does this happen? How can I get my count variable to stay the same between navigating between my 2 screens, and then upon navigating back to `index.tsx`, my `getServerSideProps` increments it by 1 as it should instead of resetting it?**

My code is below for reference:

**`index.tsx`**

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectCounter, counterActions } from '../store/slices/counter';
import { wrapper } from "../store" // for getserversideprops
import Link from "next/link";

interface HomeProps {
  test: number
}

const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = (props) => {
  const counter = useSelector(selectCounter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return (
    <>
      <h1>home, Counter: {counter.count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => { dispatch(counterActions.increment()); }}>Increment by 1</button>
      <Link href="/other">
        <a>go to OTHER PAGE</a>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async () => {
  await store.dispatch(counterActions.increment());
  return {
    props: {}
  };
});
```

**`other.tsx`**

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { counterActions, selectCounter } from "../store/slices/counter";

const Other: NextPage = () => {
    const counter = useSelector(selectCounter);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    return (
        <>
            <h1>other page, Counter: {counter.count}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => { dispatch(counterActions.increment()); }}>Increment by 1</button>
            <Link href="/">
                <a>go to HOME</a>
            </Link>
        </>
    );
}

export default Other
```

**`index.ts`** (store)

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { Action } from "redux";
import counterReducer from "../store/slices/counter";
// we can import multiple reducers here (like our counterReducer)

const makeStore = () => configureStore({
    reducer: {
        counter: counterReducer,
        // multiple reducers can go here that will be combined
    },
    devTools: true,
});

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore["getState"]>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, AppState, unknown, Action>;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(makeStore);
```

**`counter.ts`**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { AppState } from "..";

export const CounterSlice = createSlice({
    name: "counter",
    initialState: {
        count: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        increment: (state) => {
            state.count++;
        },
        // other actions or ways to mutate the data (count) go here
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
            if (!action.payload.counter.count) {
                return state;
            }
            state.count = action.payload.counter.count;
        }
    }
});

// export multiple actions here
export const counterActions = CounterSlice.actions;

export const selectCounter = (state: AppState) => state.counter;

export default CounterSlice.reducer;
```

**`_app.tsx`**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { wrapper } from "../store"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

*(I've read through the similar Stackoverflow questions, NextJS and Redux docs, and still can't figure this out)*